# rendering ionic3 data in view html

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

```
**post.html**
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
       *//Something to do here*
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>




**post.ts**
export class PostPage {
  items:any;
  displayName: string;

  firedata = firebase.database().ref('/chatusers');

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public storage:Storage,
              public userservice: UserProvider, public afireauth: AngularFireAuth) {

    this.userservice.getAllPosts().on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let posts = snapshot.val();
      let keys = Object.keys(posts);
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let k = keys[i];
        let postArray = posts[k].post;
        let displayName = posts[k].displayName;

        for (let j = 0; j < postArray.length; j++) {
          let itemList = postArray[j];
          console.log(displayName + " : " + itemList);
        }
      }
    });
  }


**console.log output**
TANMAY : PDP
TANMAY : ALGO TA
TANMAY : smoking kills
SIDDHANT : Bad Grades
SIDDHANT : boytown
SIDDHANT : smoothy
```

I want this exact output which is displayed in console.log to be displayed in my HTML, For some reason I am unable to do, please help me, I have got everything ready, just need a way to get it rendered in my HTML. New to Ionic3.

Comment: Which data list you need to show on the `html`?

Comment: console.log(displayName + " : " + itemList);
So need to show the name and the itemList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it as shown below.

**Note:** Later you can convert this to typed array instead of `any` (i.e.  `myArray:any=[]`).

According to your use case select the `lifecycle event`. I have chosen `ionViewDidLoad`.

*ts*

```
myArray:any=[];

constructor(){}

 ionViewDidLoad(){    
   this.userservice.getAllPosts().on('value', (Gotdata) => {
      let posts = Gotdata.val();
      let keys = Object.keys(posts);
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let k = keys[i];
        let postObj = posts[k].post;
        let displayName = posts[k].displayName;

        for (let j = 0; j < postObj.length; j++) {
          let itemList = postObj[j];
          let arrayObj={displayName :displayName ,item:itemList }
          this.myArray.push(arrayObj);//array
        }
      }
    });
}
```

*.html*

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
     <ion-list>
       <ion-item *ngFor="let m of myArray" >
       <ion-label>{{m.displayName}}</ion-label>
       <ion-label>{{m.item }}</ion-label>
       </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Worked:) Thanks alot

Comment: One issue that i spotted is that,you have put the JS code in ionViewDidEnter(). 
The issue with this is, whenever i switch tabs this lets called again so the data gets rendered again and again.
Any way to change it?

Comment: You can change the event.Use `ionViewDidLoad()`.